# Tikz/pgfplots shade to origin (polar)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, polarplot

I'm trying to shade in just one petal of a polar function. Specifically, I was wondering if there was a way to shade in the bounded region that lives between my two rays:

[image]

I've tried searching for examples elsewhere but most of the ones I've seen involve either shading in a region bounded by *two* curves or shading in the area under a function y=f(x).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    smooth,
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal]
\addplot [domain=0:pi, samples=150, red]
         ({2*sin(5*x)*cos(x)}, {2*sin(5*x)*sin(x)});
\draw [-stealth, ultra thick, dashed, draw=blue] 
        (axis cs: 0,0)
        -- ++(canvas polar cs: radius=3cm,angle=0);
\draw [-stealth, ultra thick, dashed, draw=blue] 
        (axis cs: 0,0)
        -- ++(canvas polar cs: radius=4cm,angle=deg{pi/5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you know the coordinates, just use `fill`.

```
\fill[blue,opacity=0.4] (o) -- (a) -- (b);
```

Note that I have the named the coordinates. See the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    smooth,
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal]
\addplot [domain=0:pi, samples=150, red] ({2*sin(5*x)*cos(x)}, {2*sin(5*x)*sin(x)});
\draw [-stealth, ultra thick, dashed, draw=blue] (axis cs: 0,0)coordinate(o)
        -- ++(canvas polar cs: radius=3cm,angle=0)coordinate(a);
\draw [-stealth, ultra thick, dashed, draw=blue] (o)
    -- ++(canvas polar cs: radius=4cm,angle=deg{pi/5})coordinate(b);
\fill[blue,opacity=0.4] (o) -- (a) -- (b);
%  for filling the petal
% \addplot [domain=0:pi/5, samples=30, red,fill=blue!40] ({2*sin(5*x)*cos(x)}, {2*sin(5*x)*sin(x)}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

#### EDIT

If you want only the petal to be shaded, then you can use the `\addplot` to fill.

```
\addplot [domain=0:pi/5, samples=30, red,fill=blue!40] ({2*sin(5*x)*cos(x)}, {2*sin(5*x)*sin(x)});
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!  I should've been more clear in my question.  I only wanted to shade in just the region bounded by the function.  Specifically, I just want to shade in the petal.

Comment: @DonnieNathanChad See the edit.

Answer (score 4):

You could just add a plot that you shade.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal]
\addplot[stealth-stealth, ultra thick, dashed, draw=blue,fill=blue!30]  
  coordinates {(2,0) (0,0) ({3*cos(pi/5)},{3*sin(pi/5)})};
\addplot [smooth,domain=0:pi, samples=150, red]
         ({2*sin(5*x)*cos(x)}, {2*sin(5*x)*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]